# Sum in case expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, left-join, window-functions

I am writing a code in SQL Server 2017 Windows 10. I don't know where the issue is and I can't get the result of total in case expression.

Here is my code

```
select PD.PONO, PM.CURRSTATUS, PD.Qty
    , case when pm.currstatus = 1 then sum(pd.qty) end TotalStock
from ppom PM
LEFT OUTER join ppod PD on pd.pono = pm.pono
where pm.pono = 15973
group by PD.PONO, PM.CURRSTATUS, PD.Qty
GO
```

Result is showing below

```
PONO    CURRSTATUS  Qty TotalStock
15973   1   8   8
15973   1   14  14
15973   1   25  25
```

While result should show the sum value

```
PONO    CURRSTATUS  Qty TotalStock
15973          1    8   47
15973          1    14  47
15973          1    25  47
```

Please help me in this thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want a window sum rather than aggregation. It would look like:

```
select 
    pd.pono, 
    pm.currstatus, 
    pd.qty,
    sum(case when pm.currstatus = 1 then pd.qty else 0 end) 
        over(partition by pd.pono) total_stock
from ppom pm
left join ppod pd on pd.pono = pm.pono
```